# How to add checkbox column into grid view using Windows form VB.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

```
Public Class Recipients
Private Sub Recipients_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    mycom.Connection = cn
    mycom.CommandText = "Select Idno,Name,Course,YearSec,Organization from tbl_students"
    myr = mycom.ExecuteReader

    While myr.Read
        With grdRecipients
            .Rows.Add()
            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(0).Value = myr(0).ToString
            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(1).Value = myr(1).ToString
            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(2).Value = myr(2).ToString
            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(3).Value = myr(3).ToString
            .Rows(.RowCount - 1).Cells(4).Value = myr(4).ToString
        End With
    End While
    myr.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

I have a grid view called grdRecipients which loads the data in my database using the select statement. Column names are manually inputted in the data grid view.
Any help with automatically creating their own column names and adding a checkbox column.

Any help is apprecited. . . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automatically create the column names, you can create a DataTable based on the SQL query and set it as a source to the DataGridView. To have a CheckBox column, there must be a column in the DataTable with a Boolean data type. It can be either manually created or it can be retrieved from the query.

Check the following code for more information

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    mycom.Connection = cn
    mycom.CommandText =
        <SQL>
            SELECT
                Idno
                ,Name
                ,Course
                ,YearSec
                ,Organization
            FROM tbl_students
        </SQL>.Value

    If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        cn.Open()
    End If

    Dim myadap As New SqlDataAdapter(mycom)
    Dim mydt As New DataTable
    myadap.Fill(mydt)

    mydt.Columns.Add("CheckBoxColumn", GetType(Boolean))
    grdRecipients.DataSource = mydt

    myadap.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: **Value of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand'**
I get this error on the line: `Dim myadap As New SqlDataAdapter(mycom)`

Comment: Replace the line `Dim myadap As New SqlDataAdapter(mycom)` to `Dim myadap As New MySqlDataAdapter(mycom)`

Comment: @ David, thanks great help, your comment satisfied my problem, any knowledge on how to get the values selected?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to check the checkboxes right? to check a checkbox, you can set the value of the corresponding row for the `CheckBoxColumn` to `true`. For example if you want to check the first row's checkbox, you can use this line `mydt.rows(0).item("CheckBoxColumn") = true`. The 0 represent the index of the first line. The row must exist before you can check its checkbox.

Comment: what i mean is, from the code you gave me, except the `mydt.rows(0).item("CheckBoxColumn") = true`, how can i allow the checkboxes to be checked and how can i get the values of the checked rows and pass it to the other form?
thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to check all the rows, just create a loop and use the counter variable of that loop as an index for the row that you want to check `mydt.rows(CounterVariable).item("CheckBoxColumn") = true`. To pass the checked values to another form, you can simply declare the DataTable mydt in a Module so that it becomes visible in the other form as well.

Comment: by the way, 'mydt.rows(0).item("CheckBoxColumn") = true' only allow one specific row to be checked, can you help me with allowing a checkbox to be checked by me, not actually appearing to be already checked when i didn't yet do anything

Comment: and by the way how can you add a check box in the header column of the check box column, that when that check box is checked all of the checkboxes in the datagridview will be checked 
thanks